# Como colocar 3 parametros no value do input? Laravel 5.7

Tags: php-7, laravel-blade

Preciso colocar um valor default em um input do tipo texto.

O valor default será 'Brasil', porém estou usando o helper old no blade e não sei como inserir este valor default. o código que estou utilizando é este.

```
<input type="text" name="address_province" value="{{ old('address_province', @$geral->address_province) }}">
```

tentei utilizar o or após o valor da váriavel `$geral`, mas não funcionou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de procurar um pouco, achei uma solução que atendeu ao meu problema, basta inserir no value um terceiro parâmetro usando o operador ternário `?:`.

Exemplo.

```
<input type="text" name="address_province" value="{{ old('address_province', @$geral->address_province) ?: 'Portugal' }}">
```

Usando o operador ternário foi possível inserir mais um valor para o `value` do `input`, pois ele verifica se existe dados no `helper old()` e se não encontrar execute o que vier depois do `?:`.